# Canny lines from depth image (CFD)

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, canny-operator

I am a bit confused about the term "Canny lines from depth image (CFD)".

So when I read in papers they used Canny line detection on depth images they mean that the input image is something like [this](http://fab.cba.mit.edu/classes/863.13/people/ermal/mas.863/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/front.jpg)?

So it is basically a 2D image, where each pixel's color is replaced by the depth information, which is like a grey scale image, right?

EDIT:
Here is a paper as a [reference](http://cybertron.cg.tu-berlin.de/eitz/projects/sbsr/) for example.

Comment: your question is not clear! Please site some reference to the original paper/question

Comment: My misunderstanding has been clarified, but I added a reference paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a disparity map (or disparity image) the greyscale value maps into distance from the camera. 
I wouldn't call it a 3D image, that's probably confusing. But it does represent 3D data, some 3D displays (Philips) use this as their data format and so will display this as a stereo image.

ps. It is nothing directly to do with Canny - that is an algorithm for finding edges in an image (which is often a first step in making a stereo image)

Comment: My confusion lies in, that even if they say they are detecting Canny lines in a depth image it is still a 2D image and not a point cloud or if I can say so a 3D image, right?

Comment: @Silex just a simple 2D 1 channel image, so basically a grayscale image. It's not a 3D image.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!